# What is the Shortest possible formula to find the intersection between a set of two ranges of number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to find the intersection between a set of two ranges of number.

let me explain the question with an example,

```
{2,3} {3,8} would result to 0
{2,5} {3,8} would result to 2
{3,6} {3,8} would result to 3
{4,5} {3,8} would result to 1
{4,5} {3,8} would result to 1
{8,9} {3,8} would result to 0
```

Note:This could be easily done with series of if in a computer application, I am hungry for a mathematical solution!

Comment: By "intersection", you mean the number of "units" of overlap between the two given intervals?

Comment: What are "tow ranges"?

Comment: @ J.M yes , and @ Pete L.Clark I mean set of two numbers

Comment: There is a great grief about this notation of yours, $(3,8)$ usually indicates all the real numbers which are strictly greater than $3$ and strictly smaller than $8$. Not just the integers, which is what seems to be your meaning.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I have changed to {,} I am new so not sure this is correct ,thanks

Comment: @Thunder: This is still not correct. But nevermind, I hope that whoever reads the question will look at my answer and figure out the correct meaning anyway.

Comment: For those curious, the correct notation would be [,] for inclusive values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have $\{x,x+1,\ldots,x+n\}$ and $\{y,y+1,\ldots,y+k\}$ and granted $x,y$ are integers you want to find out the number of elements in the intersections (i.e. how many numbers appear in both sets).

Well, take: $$\max\{0,\min\{y+k,x+n\}-\max\{x,y\}\}$$ and that should be it.

Comment: well the result is not a set but a number , that represents the value in the intersection set.

Comment: @Thunder: Yes, and Asaf's construction does return the number you (seem to) want.

Comment: yes this the correct answer ... thanks